# Android - SharedPreference.getBoolean retrieving false even if i am storing true?

Tags: android, checkbox, state, sharedpreferences

I am using SharedPreference to store the state of checkboxes but even i am storing true in it , its still retrieving false.

Here is my code -

```
@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    saveState();
}


@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    loadState();

}
@Override
public void onRestart()
{
    super.onRestart();
    loadState();
}

public void saveState()
{
    SharedPreferences sp = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
    for(int i = 0; i < itemCheck.length; i++)
    {
        Boolean b = itemCheck[i];
        Log.e(TAG, b.toString());
        editor.putBoolean(i+"", itemCheck[i]);
    }
}
public void loadState()
{
    SharedPreferences sp = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    for(int i = 0; i < itemCheck.length; i++)
    {

        itemCheck[i] = sp.getBoolean(i+"", false);
        Boolean b = itemCheck[i];
        Log.e(TAG, b.toString());
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < itemCheck.length; i++)
    {
        lv.setItemChecked(i, itemCheck[i]);
    }
}
```

Its giving me false because i set false as a default value in getBoolean which should be returned in the absence of predefined key. Please take a look and tell me what i did wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never call `commit()` on your [editor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#commit%28%29) I think :)
Try this:

```
public void saveState()
{
    SharedPreferences sp = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
    for(int i = 0; i < itemCheck.length; i++)
    {
        Boolean b = itemCheck[i];
        Log.e(TAG, b.toString());
        editor.putBoolean(i+"", itemCheck[i]);
    }
    editor.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use `editor.commit()` after  `editor.putBoolean(i+"", itemCheck[i]);`